# How to combine a voltage and current booster in one circuit

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am trying to design a voltage-current booster stepping voltage and current from 2.5V-15V and 2mA-2A. I have searched quite a number of sites but each of them is giving a different design and it caused confusion. May you at least give me a head start where to specifically start with the design.

Comment: It sounds like you want to magically increase the overall power. Good luck with that...

Comment: Basic law of physics - Energy out is always equal or less than energy in. If not, we'd all be riding around in cars powered by perpetual motion engines.  Yah canna change the laws of physics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because what is required is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can convert 2.5V 2mA to 15V 2A.

... but there's no magic, what you lose is continuous operation.

If this is really what you need, you have to add some energy storage.

First step 2.5V 2mA up to 15V (you'll easily find a circuit to do that) - you'll only get 2mA/6 or 0.3mA (plus some losses).

Charge a large capacitor from that - it'll take some time to reach 15V. 
(Other forms of energy storage work too : pumping water uphill, raising a weight, winding a spring, or even batteries). But when it does reach 15V, you can get 2A from it for a short pulse, which will partially discharge it, then you'll have to wait until it's fully charged again before the next pulse.

Conservation of energy tells you the best you can do : if you start with 2.5V 2mA, (0.005W) and need 15V 2A (30W) for a 1 second pulse (30J), you'll need to wait 6000 seconds (30/0.005) ignoring losses, or about 2 hours (7200 seconds, with very careful design for efficiency) before the next pulse.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I also need help on the design of the circuit. I would like some assistance on that too.

Answer (score 2):

You can either convert current into voltage, or voltage into current (crudely speaking). You cannot ever convert voltage into more voltage and current into more current without the addition of more voltage and current.

Basically P=VI. P must remain constant, so if you increase V then I must decrease.

Note for the pedants: I am intentionally ignoring conversion efficiency.